# ゼロから作るディープラーニング１からの質問　エラーの箇所を修正したい

Tags: python, python3

エラーが出ていてどこを直しせばいいのかわかりません、おそらく55行目からのfor文ないを訂正すればよいと思うのですが。

```
import sys, os
import numpy as np
sys.path.append(os.pardir)
from dataset.mnist import load_mnist
import pickle
from common.functions import sigmoid, softmax


# テスト用のデータを出力する関数を作成
def get_data():
    # MNISTデータセットを読み込み
    (x_train, t_train), (x_test, t_test) = load_mnist(normalize=True, flatten=True, one_hot_label=False)
    
    # テスト用のデータを出力
    return x_test, t_test

# 学習済みのパラメータを読み込む関数を実装
def init_network():
    
    # 学習済みのパラメータの読み込み
    with open("./deep-learning-from-scratch-master/ch03/sample_weight.pkl", 'rb') as f:
        network = pickle.load(f)
        
        # 学習済みパラメータを格納したディクショナリを出力
        return network

# 手書き数字から正解を予測する関数を実装
def predict(network, x):
    # ディクショナリから学習済みパラメータを取得
    W1, W2, W3 = network['W1'], network['W2'], network['W3']
    b1, b2, b3 = network['b1'], network['b2'], network['b3']
    
    # 第1層の計算
    a1 = np.dot(x, W1) + b1 # 重み付き和
    z1 = sigmoid(a1) # 活性化
    
    # 第2層の計算
    a2 = np.dot(z1, W2) + b2 # 重み付き和
    z2 = sigmoid(a2) # 活性化
    
    # 第3層の計算
    a3 = np.dot(z2, W3) + b3 # 重み付き和
    y = softmax(a3) # 活性化
    
    # 推論結果(ニューラルネットワークの出力)を出力
    return y

   # テスト画像とテストラベルを取得
x, t = get_data()

# 学習済みパラメータを取得
network=init_network

accuracy_cnt = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
    y = predict(network, x[i])
    p= np.argmax(y) # 最も確率の高い要素のインデックスを取得
    if p == t[i]:
        accuracy_cnt += 1

print("Accuracy:" + str(float(accuracy_cnt) / len(x)))
```

エラーの内容

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\deep-learning-from-scratch-master\3.6.2.py", line 56, in <module>
    y = predict(network, x[i])
  File "c:\deep-learning-from-scratch-master\3.6.2.py", line 30, in predict
    W1, W2, W3 = network['W1'], network['W2'], network['W3']
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

問題は2点あると思われます。
発生しているエラーそのものは以下の2つ目が原因で、関数を呼び出した結果の戻り値を代入すべきところが、関数オブジェクトを代入しているからですね。
それが`TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`というエラーにつながる間違いです。

誤：

```
# 学習済みのパラメータを読み込む関数を実装
def init_network():
    
    # 学習済みのパラメータの読み込み
    with open("./deep-learning-from-scratch-master/ch03/sample_weight.pkl", 'rb') as f:
        network = pickle.load(f)
        
        # 学習済みパラメータを格納したディクショナリを出力
        return network
```

正：`return`のインデントが違うので1段戻す

```
# 学習済みのパラメータを読み込む関数を実装
def init_network():
    
    # 学習済みのパラメータの読み込み
    with open("./deep-learning-from-scratch-master/ch03/sample_weight.pkl", 'rb') as f:
        network = pickle.load(f)
    
    # 学習済みパラメータを格納したディクショナリを出力
    return network
```

---

誤：

```
# 学習済みパラメータを取得
network=init_network
```

正：`()`を付けて関数を呼び出した結果を代入する

```
# 学習済みパラメータを取得
network=init_network()
```

---

ちなみにこちらにソースコードが格納されています。
[deep-learning-from-scratch/ch03/neuralnet_mnist.py](https://github.com/oreilly-japan/deep-learning-from-scratch/blob/master/ch03/neuralnet_mnist.py)